# Kendo-ui Grid: Can the standard HTML5 input date-time be used as a cell editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been trying to use the standard html5 input as a cell editor in the kendo-ui grid
ie

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="1996-12-19T16:39:57" />
```

I like this one over the datetime widget as you can use the arrow key to go to each date time component and then use up down arrows to edit that part of the date time.

I have tried defining the following cell template function..

```
 function timeEditor(container, options) {
    var input = $('<input "datetime-local" name="' + options.field +'" />')
   input.appendTo(container);        
 }
```

and giving this to the appropriate field in the columns definition..

```
columns: [
  {
    field: "Time",
    title: "Time",
    width: "180px",
    editor: timeEditor,       
  },
```

The editor is instantiated (I get a breakpoint in it hit), but I do not get the control appearing as expected.

I am rather new to the kendo ui (I am trialling it), so perhaps I have dome something simple wrong here? Or is it possible to use this?

Thanks in advance for any help
regards, Peter

Comment: do be aware that "datetime-local" inputs don't work in a lot of browsers.

Comment: Thanks for that @dandavis  I see that (after some Googling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going it right, except that your HTML is wrong.

```
<input "datetime-local ...
```

is missing the `type=` atrribute name, and should be:

```
<input type="datetime-local ...
```

Also keep in mind that in a custom editor, you will have to do the work of setting the value, and updating your data if someone changes the value of the input box, so you will probably want to add a `.on('change' ...)` event handler too.

A fully working editor would look something like this:

```
function timeEditor(container, options) {
    var input = $('<input type="datetime-local" name="'
        + options.field
        +'" value="'
        + options.model.get(options.field)
        + '" />');
    input.on('change', options.model.set(options.field, input.val()));
    input.appendTo(container);        
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that @CodeWithSpike! That certainly seems to work now. What a bummer it looks like support for this control is minimal (as mentioned above), it probably one of the best controls I've seen to handle both date and time (the one I get in Chrome at least).